# How does 2017 MS Security Patches Supersedes?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a 2008 R2 SP1 server, recently it was flagged out that I missed a critical patch **[KB4022722](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHUtf.png)**.

However I assumed that patching **[KB4025337](https://i.stack.imgur.com/034hp.png)** addresses the issue since MS patches are cumulative. Upon further verification that it did not supersede **KB4022722**.

The superseded KB list of **KB4025337** does not even mention the previous MS patch Tuesday KB4034679 released on 6/13/2017.

Thus my question is how does MS patches superseding work exactly?

Comment: The fact that they release a cumulative update pack does not mean that all updates are cumulative.